# Exercise 3, Section 5.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $F$ is **skew-symmetric** if $A^t=-A$. If $A$ is a skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries and $n$ is odd, prove that $\text{det}(A) = 0$.

**My attempt:** Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, we have $\text{det}(A)= \text{det}(A^t)= \text{det}(-A)$. By theorem 2 section 5.3, $$\text{det}(-A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn}\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n-A(i,\sigma (i))= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn}\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n (-1)\cdot A(i,\sigma (i))=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn}\sigma)(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^nA(i,\sigma (i))= (-1)^n\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn}\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^nA(i,\sigma(i))=(-1)^n\cdot \text{det}(A).$$ Since $n$ is odd, we have $(-1)^n=-1$. So $\text{det}(-A)=-1\cdot \text{det}(A)=-\text{det}(A)$. Thus $\text{det}(A)= -\text{det}(A)$. By distributive property of field, $\text{det}(A)+\text{det}(A)=(1+1)\cdot \text{det}(A)=0$. Which implies $1+1=0$ or $\text{det}(A)=0$. Since $1+1=2\neq 0$, we have $\text{det}(A)=0$. Hence $\text{det}(A)=0$. **Is my proof correct?**

Here $1$ denotes $(1,0)\in \Bbb{C}$. If $n$ is odd, then $(-1)^n=-1$, and if $n$ is even, then $(-1)^n=1$, is generalization of proposition $1.16$ (c), (d) of Baby Rudin. I think, this problem can be generalize to arbitrary field $F$ such that $1+1\neq 0$, i.e. $\text{char}(F)\neq 2$. **Am I right?**

---

**Edit:** There is a slick way to show $\text{det}(-A)= (-1)^n\cdot \text{det}(A)$. Following is proof of @blargoner. Let $A\in M_n(K)$ with rows $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n$. Since det is $n$-linear, we have
$$\begin{align*} \text{det}(-A)&= \text{det}(-\alpha_1,…,-\alpha_n)\\ &=(-1)\cdot \text{det}(\alpha_1,-\alpha_2,…,-\alpha_n)\\ &=(-1)^2 \cdot \text{det}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,-\alpha_3,…,-\alpha_n)\\ &=(-1)^n\cdot \text{det}(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n)\\ &=(-1)^n \cdot \text{det}(A) \end{align*}$$ I kind of made proof long by using [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwihiPTe4df6AhXyALcAHU0kAewQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLeibniz_formula_for_determinants&usg=AOvVaw1Xt-YHY3lLnCIZusqZPyYf).

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: Not sure what “theorem 2 Section 5.3” is, so it's hard to say. You are assuming the result that $\det A^t = \det A$; has that been proven?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang There are lots of way to write det function. I used the “famous” one. That’s why I referenced theorem 2 section 5.3. Yes, $\text{det}(A^t)=\text{det}(A)$ is proven.

Comment: Why thing (featured on meta, related, hot network questions) on right side of post is popping up, making post tiny. Usually it is below the post.

Comment: @user264745 It depends on the width of your browser window.

Comment: note that if you use an improved definition of skew-symmetry, i.e. that $A^T = -A$ *and* all diagonals are zero, then this result holds over characteristic 2 as well.

Comment: $\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$ is immediate from $n$-linearity of the determinant in rows or columns, no need to break out the Leibniz expansion.